# repeating macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a marcro that can copy and paste cells.

The value of cell X must be copied to a cell X + 6.
So A1 text "Xteam" has to be copied to cell A7, this up to cell A380.
The same applies to cell B2 + 6.

It has to be dynamic, so the cell and sequence are dynamic.. 
I want to be able to indicate for myself which cell it is and the sequence ..

How can I do this,

I have this but doesnot work like i want:

```
Sub sequence()
Const Nxt As Long = 7
Dim A As Variant, B As Variant, V As Variant, N As Long
A = Range("A1").Value
B = Range("B2").Value
ReDim V(Nxt To 380, 1 To 2)
For N = Nxt To 380
    If N Mod 6 = 1 Then
        V(N, 1) = A
        V(N + 1, 2) = B
    End If
Next N
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A" & Nxt, "B380").Value = V
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

thank you in advance 
elmalle

Comment: What do you mean a maximum number of times copied? Don't you just want A7 - A380?

Comment: yes,  thats for now the best.. sorry for that..

Comment: well I've made it so that you have to specify in the code how many repetitions you want, but if you want it to end at 380 its about 63 repetitions so just edit that line and it should work how you want

Answer (score 1):

Ok well, this is under the assumption that you want to specify how many times you want to copy `A1` and `B2` down the sheet. So your loop is fairly confusing, instead of using MOD, since you know you want it every 6 spaces and you're not doing anything to the other cells, it's easier just to have the number multiplied by 6 for your indexing. This also helps you figure out the dimensions of your transfer arrays more easily since you want to specify how many times you want to copy.

It's also worth noting that you're `Application.screenupdating = False` is in the wrong place. The real place you would want to speed up is during the loop. So if you were to include it, I would put it near the top of the code, but this isn't very resource intensive so I've just left it out.

Normally it's good to `dim Constants` if it helps with the legibility of the code, but in this case it doesn't seem to add any clarity. An example where it could help is where you're changing the colour of cells and are using colour indices. `Constant Red as long = 3` makes it a lot more understandable, whereas `constant Nxt as long = 7` doesn't add much.

Instead of working with a 2-D array dealing with both `A` and `B` at once, I chose to use two column vectors because it makes the pasting easier since they are staggered and it simplifies the math since you don't need to have items on staggered rows.

Lastly, I can't advocate this enough, but ***please, please, please*** use names that make sense at a glance. Although it may not have made a huge difference in this case, if you get to a more complicated project people might look at it and have to wonder what `V` is even used for. It also just makes it easier for people to help you since they won't have to sit for a bit wondering what each variable means.

I've also specified the worksheet it looks at, so currently it'll only look at the first sheet as indicated by the index 1. Make sure you change that so it changes the correct sheet.

Hope this helped and welcome to Stack Overflow.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sequence()

    Dim A As Variant
    Dim B As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim ArrA() As Variant
    Dim ArrB() As Variant
    Dim NumCopies As Long

    A = Range("A1").Value
    B = Range("B2").Value
    NumCopies = 100

    ReDim Preserve ArrA(1 To NumCopies * 6, 1 To 1)
    ReDim Preserve ArrB(1 To NumCopies * 6, 1 To 1)

    For N = 1 To NumCopies
        ArrA(N * 6, 1) = A
        ArrB(N * 6, 1) = B
    Next N


    Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & 1 + NumCopies * 6).Value = ArrA
    Worksheets(1).Range("B3:B" & 2 + NumCopies * 6).Value = ArrB

End Sub
```